# How to set precision to 2 in while writing in excel using perl?

Tags: excel, perl, file, format

I need to write some nos into excel file using perl.
For ex, let the nos be 10 , 11.25 , 6.15.

I have no issues with 11.25 and 6.15 because they get written as they are. 
But I want 10 to be written as 10.00

My code is as:

```
    my $Amountformat = $workbook1->add_format();
    my $Amountformat->set_num_format(0x02);
    $worksheet1->write_number($row,$col,$Amount,$Amountformat);
```

On doing so I get error as "Can't call method "set_num_format" on an undefined value at header.pl"

I tried with

```
    my $Amountformat->set_num_format('0x02'); and 
    my $Amountformat->set_num_format("0x02");
```

but still i get the same error.

My header files are use

```
    Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
    use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
```

I am unable to understand the cause of error as i am new to perl.
Can you pls help me resolve the error, or guide me some alternative using which i can write 10 as 10.00 in excel file.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're re-declaring `$AmountFormat` with `my` when you call `set_num_format`. The second use of `my $AmountFormat` creates a new undefined variable with the same as the old one. Remove the second `my` and it should work.

You should also add

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

to stop Perl from allowing this to happen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But what i meant is that I used both the statements individually. I mean, i ran my code with the first statement only and then I ran the code with only the second statement. In either case I get the same error.  Also, I have used use strict and use warnings.

Comment: Yes I assumed they were run separately. The problem is that within each of those statements, you use my twice. my should only be used when initially declaring the variable.